# LOCK_TASK_FEATURE_GLOBAL_ACTIONS alternative for API 26

Tags: android

I'm looking for some way to block users from turning kiosk device off with only touch screen. Unfortunately, all devices I'm programming for run on api <= 26, so I can't simply use `setLockTaskFeatures`, with `LOCK_TASK_FEATURE_GLOBAL_ACTIONS`. How else can I stop users from powering the kiosk device off using the power button in the navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no way to do that, the setLockTaskFeatures() is added in API 28.
If it was there in the previous APIs it would be implemented by setGlobalSetting(), which it's almost deprecated now and neither does have any parameter corresponding to power-button.